# Porting part of Selenium IDE to chrome extension

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-ide, katalon-recorder

I have been trying to port Selenium IDE into a chrome extension I have been working on but to no avail. Specifically, I want to be able to execute selenium-built commands (e.g. `click`, `assertElementVisible`, etc.) in my extension.

I am aware that porting Selenium into another extension has been done before ([Katalon Recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?hl=en-US)), but I could find absolutely nothing online on how the porting was done.

That said, can anyone give me some pointers on:

- Specifically what files I should port from the IDE repository
- How to set up and call Selenium commands in my extension
- How I may properly accredit Selenium in my use of its code

I am aware that the old Selenium IDE is deprecated, so I plan on using the new Selenium IDE on [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide). The new IDE is still under development, but I believe that the functionalities that I require are ready to be used at this moment (I only require running commands on DOM elements).